# "OS Authentication" delphi

Tags: oracle, delphi, authentication, oracle11g, dbexpress

I have Oracle XE 11g running on Windows 7 host
I am able to connect to Oracle using OS Authentication in SQLPlus
I am able to connect to Oracle in Delphi using TSQLConnection with username and password

When I blank the username and password in SQLConnection.Params and set OSAuthentication and/or OS Authentication (all combinations) params to True and attempt to set Connected to True I get:

ORA-01017: invalid username/password; Logon denied;

Has anyone connected to Oracle using OS Authentication using Delphi and dbExpress?

Comment: `TSQLConnection` uses the user associated with the calling thread unless told otherwise.  So try using Win32 impersonation when  connecting with a blank username/password.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Win32 impersonation. Wouldn't the user associated with the calling thread be %userdomain%\%username% ? When I do a Windows API call to get those values they are what my Oracle server would expect for OS Authentication.

Comment: Impersonation is done using [`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612.aspx) or related function. The user associated with the thread is the user who started the app's process by default, unless the thread impersonates another user programmably.

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to Oracle XE 11g running on my Windows 7 host through sqlplus running on the same host the Oracle account expected is "OPS$%userdomain%\%username%". When connecting remotely through a Linux VM only "OPS$%username%" is expected. When running Delphi on the same Windows 7 host the TSqlConnection seems to be acting like a remote connection, so I was able to use OS Authentication when logged in to Windows as %username% using the Oracle "OPS$%username% user. Hope that makes sense.